# Simple way to combine many observables into one object

Tags: angular, rxjs, javascript-objects, ngrx

I need to build an object from couple of observables that comes from the ngrx state.

```
    public readonly comibiedToOneObject$ = zip(
    this.store$.select(selectObs1),
    this.store$.select(selectObs2),
    this.store$.select(selectObs3),

    ...

    this.store$.select(selectObsN),
  ).pipe(
    map(([
           obs1,
           obs2,
           obs3,

            ...

           obsN
         ]) => {
      return {
           obs1,
           obs2,
           obs3,

            ...

           obsN
      };
    }),
  );
```

How can i make this more readable and better code?

Comment: do you need the object just once? or whenever all values have changed in the store?

Comment: Just once .....

Comment: Then I'd suggest the `forkJoin` operator. It has a syntax where you can pass an object with Observable properties, like in my answer below. But you'd need completing observables, so you'd have to put `pipe(first())` after all your input observables. If you don't want this, you can use the library I've mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend `zipObject` from the [rxjs-etc](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-etc) package. It's an extension library by one of the main contributors of RxJS.

Usage:

```
zipObject({
    obs1: this.store$.select(selectObs1),
    obs2: this.store$.select(selectObs2),
    obs3: this.store$.select(selectObs3),

    ...

    obs9: this.store$.select(selectObs9)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```js
merge(
  obs1$.pipe(map((v) => ['obs1', v])),
  obs2$.pipe(map((v) => ['obs2', v])),
  obs3$.pipe(map((v) => ['obs3', v])),
  /* ... */
  obsN$.pipe(map((v) => ['obsN', v])),
).pipe(
  scan((acc, ([k, v])) => {
    acc[k] = v;

    return acc;
  }, {})
)
```

I believe that `zip` has more specific use-cases, other than just combining the observable's values into one object.

Answer (score 0):

You may combine two observables...to reach the response data when both have responded already.

```
fetchData(): Observable<any[]> {
    return combineLatest(
        this.observable1$(),
        this.observable2$()
    );
}
```

duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/62033110/1

Answer (score 0):

```
let observables = [selectObs1,selectObs2,selectObs3].map((obs) => this.store$.select(obs));

public readonly comibiedToOneObject$ = forkJoin(observables).pipe(map(res) => ({...res}));
```